# How can I hide all major / minor modes from the mode line without a package?

Tags: emacs, modeline

After coming from Spacemacs where the performance was a bit slow, I'm rebuilding my config from scratch atm with a focus on performance and was wondering, how can I hide all major and minor modes from the modeline without installing additional packages?

For context, I can tell what major mode I'm in by the file name suffix or buffer name and there isn't much need to be reminded what minor modes are available since that gets built into muscle memory from daily usage of emacs.

Answer (score 2):

```el
(setq-default mode-line-format (delq 'mode-line-modes mode-line-format))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Not sure if one of my other modes is interfering with it like winum or evil mode

Comment: Does it work when you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: In general you want to remove `mode-line-modes` from your `mode-line-format`; but if you've customized the latter then you'll need to figure out where the format is now positioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that in spacemacs, you can add

```lisp
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()

  (spaceline-toggle-minor-modes-off)

)
```

to your `.spacemacs`. Or call that function interactively `SPC t m m`